# VBA Excel Import .txt with User-Input file name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to have a user enter the file name of a text file (not the entire C:\ thing, but just the name) that is to be imported into an excel spreadsheet. I've already got the code for inputting the text file (space delimited) to the spreadsheet, but I'd really like to not go back and change the code every time I want to import another text file. Is this possible? The file is currently called data.txt, but it will most likely be in the form Data_MM_DD_YY

My current code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub ImportTextFile(FName As String, Sep As String)

Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim TempVal As Variant
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim Pos As Integer
Dim NextPos As Integer
Dim SaveColNdx As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


SaveColNdx = ActiveCell.Column
RowNdx = ActiveCell.Row

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

Name = InputBox("Enter the name of the text file")


While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    If Right(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then
        WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep
    End If
    ColNdx = SaveColNdx
    Pos = 1
    NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    While NextPos >= 1
        TempVal = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
        Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = TempVal
        Pos = NextPos + 1
        ColNdx = ColNdx + 1
        NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    Wend
    RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
Wend

EndMacro:
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close #1
End Sub

Sub DoTheImport()
ImportTextFile FName:="C:\Users\A0K045\Documents\Name).txt", Sep:=" "
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And if it's not possible, is there anything similar to this that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You just want the filename to be changed outside VBA? Sure, that's no problem.

You could create a form with a textbox for the filename, then append the directory to the string.

Or you could let the user input the filename into a spreadsheet cell and take the name from there.

This is how it would work with the input being given in a worksheet:

```
Sub DoTheImport(ByVal strFilename As String)
    strFilename = "C:\Users\A0K045\Documents\" & strFilename
    ImportTextFile FName:=strFilename, Sep:=" "
End Sub
Sub getFilenameFromSheetAndGo()
    Dim strFilename As String
    strFilename = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("InputFilename").Cells(1, 1).Value 'Cell A1
    Call DoTheImport(strFilename)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there something specific I need to type into cell A1 for the file name? I've tried data and data.txt and "data" and "data.txt", and I keep getting a subscript out of range error. Am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ask for the name and prepend the directory;

```
Name = InputBox("Enter the name of the text file")
If (Name = "") Then Exit Sub

open "c:\thedir\" & name for input as #1
...
```

Or you can use a file select dialog;

```
Dim result As Variant
ChDir "c:\thedir\"
result = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt),*.txt")
If (result = False) Then Exit Sub

open result for input as #1
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! If I add that to the top of the code (I put it after RowNdx = ActiveCell.Row), what do I do to the bottom part of code?

It's currently
    Sub DoTheImport()
    ImportTextFile FName:="C:\thedir\ & Name.txt", Sep:=" "
    End Sub

And it says it can't find the file
I double & triple checked the file name, don't worry